# How private data member is used by an inherited class object?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, private

Do **private members** are also **inherited**?

Why get() function was able to read variable n

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base
{
    int n;
public:
    void get()
    {
        cin >> n;
    }
    int ret()
    {
        return n;
    }
};

class inh : public base
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "hi";
    }
};

int main()
{
    inh a;
    a.get();
    a.show();
    return 0;
}
```

it worked fine regardless of the fact that n is private variable.

Comment: why exactly did you expect an error?

Comment: because private data members are not inherited

Comment: Where did you gather that?

Comment: private data members aren't supposed to inherited as per my teacher but when I tried the above code it worked. That's why I am here to gather

Comment: @Manish all members are inherited, but private ones are not *accessible* to derived classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All members of base class, private and public alike are inherited (otherwise inheritance would be *inherently* - pun intended - broken), but they keep private access modifier.

Since the inheritance itself in your example is public, `inh` has public members of `base` as it's own public members - and `a.show()` is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

It’s fine to call functions that access private data members. `private` just means you can’t access the data members themselves outside of the class

Answer (score 0):

You do not access any private members in the main:

```
int main()
{
  inh a;
  a.get(); // << calling a public method of the base class. OK!
  a.show(); // calling a public method of the inh class. OK!
  return 0;
}
```

You only access private members of the base class from the base class members:

```
class base
{
  int n;
public:
  void get()
  {
    cin >> n; // writing in my private member. OK!
  }
  int ret()
  {
    return n; // returning value of my private member. OK!
  }
};
```

This would cause an issue in main though:

```
 inh a;
 a.n = 10; // error

 base b;
 b.n = 10; // error
```